# windows remote desktop can't connect even if the firewall is off

Tags: windows-7, firewall, remote-desktop, rdp

I am trying to let my pc, which run at win7, accessible remotely, but I am able to. I did the following:

1. checking "Allow Remote assistance connection to this computer.
2. a set a password for my account.
3. I setup the port forwarding on my router.
4. set my remote desktop communction program feild in my firewall,
   ZonAlarm, to allow for everything.

yet it does not connect to my laptop remotely.

I even tried to see if I can connect to the same laptop from itself - usually it connects and try to load the windows but then fail loading. however even this test fail -

I have no other idea.

Any tips?

Comment: Never expose RDP to the internet. Use a VPN to get in to your network, then RDP across the VPN connection.

Answer (score 8):

Running Windows 7 / Service pack 1

1. Make sure account has a password and you can ping the host
2. Start Button → (Right Click Computer) → Properties
3. Select Remote Settings on left of window
4. (if not selected) Select Remote tab
5. Select Option "Allow connections… running any version…"
6. Select OK
7. Restart Host (Sometime not necessary but to be sure)
8. Try to connect
9. If above fails Start Task Mgr (Start Button → cmd → TaskMgr) or (ctrl-alt-del)
10. Select Services Tab
11. Look for "TermService"
12. Right Click TermService and select start
13. If Access Denied Error
14. On Services Window Select Services Button (Bottom Right)
15. Find "Remote Desktop Services" Right Click select Properties
16. Set Startup type to "Automatic"
17. Right Click "Remote Desktop Services" select Start

Comment: Upon further investigations I have found that If you have installed Norton AV make sure it is running or the above settings not be in affect. Stopping Norton AV and Windows Firewall (all modes) does not give access to RDS.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are forgetting something,
1.Set password for the account.
2.Check "Allow Remote assistance connection to this computer.
3.System properties>Remote>Remote Desktop>Select **"Allow connections from computer running any version of remote Desktop"**
4.open port 3389(default RDP port)

Answer (score 0):

If you changed username of the account be aware that only name that's being displayed in windows changed.

run `netplwiz` and just change account name in there - it should work fine.

Posting it here in case someone runs in same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a user to the 'Select Users' list in Remote in system properties